# Connecting Arduino Wifi shield to Arduino Uno based Mcore board

Tags: wifi, shields, pins, icsp, documentation

I am trying to connect [this mBot board](http://learn.makeblock.com/en/mcore/) to an external network, that's why I bought [the arduino wifi shield](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-wifi-shield).

I am connecting the wifi shield to the 6pins (5V MOSI GND RST SCK MISO) of the mCore.

Though when uploading any of the Wifi program example, the shield isn't even recognized.

(I've succesfully upgraded the firmware of the shield)

The thing is that I don't really understand how should ***I plug in the wifi shield*** on the mCore since I'm struggling to understand the datasheet of the mBot board.

Any advices ?

Regards,

Alex